# Pandas Python: KeyError Date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am import into python where it will automatically create a date time object.

However I want the first column to be a datetime object in Python. Data looks like

```
Date,cost
41330.66667,100
41331.66667,101
41332.66667,102
41333.66667,103
```

Current code looks like:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"F:\Sam\PJ\CSV2.csv")
data['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))

print(data)
```

Comment: The date column in the sample dataframe is not in any date format or the one specified in the code @Sam Harper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an excel datetime format. This is called a serial date. To convert from that serial date you can do this:

```
data['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp( (x - 25569) *86400.0))
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> data['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp( (x - 25569) *86400.0))
0   2013-02-25 10:00:00.288
1   2013-02-26 10:00:00.288
2   2013-02-27 10:00:00.288
3   2013-02-28 10:00:00.288
```

To assign it to `data['Date']` you just do:

```
data['Date'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp( (x - 25569) *86400.0))

#df
                     Date  cost
0 2013-02-25 16:00:00.288   100
1 2013-02-26 16:00:00.288   101
2 2013-02-27 16:00:00.288   102
3 2013-02-28 16:00:00.288   103
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, *read_csv* does not cope with date columns given as numbers.
But the good news is that *Pandas* does have a suitable function to do it.
After *read_csv* call:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date - 25569, unit='D').dt.round('ms')
```

As I undestand, your *Date* is actually the number of days since *30.12.1899*
(plus fractional part of the day).
The above "correction factor" (*25569*) works OK. For *Date == 0* it gives
just the above *start of Excel epoch* date.

Rounding to miliseconds (or maybe even seconds) is advisable.
Otherwise you will get weird effects resulting from inaccurate rounding
of fractional parts of day.
E.g. *0.33333333* corresponding to *8 hours* can be computed as
*07:59:59.999712*.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two problems here.

1. We don't know what data and columns the CSV has, but in order for pandas to pick up the date as a column, it must be a column on that csv file.
2. Apply doesn't work in place. You would have to assign the result of apply back to date, as 
   `data['Date'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))`